# How to get an "option focused" event with Material-UI's Autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

This is about [Material-UI's Autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/). I need an event telling me which autocomplete choice the user is currently focusing, either by hovering the mouse over the option, or using keyboard arrows (i.e., before he actually clicks it or presses Enter). I tried a bunch of things, this seemed like it should work but the event does not trigger:

```
<Autocomplete
  renderOption={option => (
    <div onFocus={() => console.log('option onFocus')}>{option}</div>
  )}/>
```

How would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [onMouseOver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onmouseover) to achieve the `hovering the mouse over the option`

```
renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
  <>
    <div onMouseOver={() => {console.log(option.name)}}>
      {option.name}
    ...
```

[image]

Try it online: https://stackblitz.com/edit/fvvowt-e4cwgb
which is a direct fork from the official demo in their document.